# How can I tell what category I'm in?

Tags: theme-development

When displaying a category how can I tell what category it is? Say I'm on `http://www.example.com/category/quotes`, how can I get `quotes` aside from parsing the URL? I tried `get_the_category()` but it returns an array of all the categories of the first post shown in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you category object with ID, slug and rest of info:

```
$wp_query->get_queried_object();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the category name with:

```
single_cat_title();
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that function, unfortunately I can only accept one answer and I picked Rarst's as I can make good use of the extra info returned by that method

Comment: No problem! You are welcome.